# JSON response with http, header, meta and body

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I'm trying to parse a JSON response. It is the first time I do it and I'm not sure which is the correct format from a JSON response.

From a web service I'm getting this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
{"rules": [
{ "id_categoria": "3","categoria": "cat03" },{ "id_categoria": "2","categoria": "cat02" }
     ]
   }</body>
</html>
```

Is it correct to find html, head, meta, and body tags in a JSON response?

By the way, I'm using this JSON parser: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

And I think JSON response it also incorrect. Its XML equivalent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <id_categoria>3</id_categoria>
    <categoria>cat03</categoria>
</rukes>
<rules>
    <id_categoria>2</id_categoria>
    <categoria>cat02</categoria>
</rules>
```

Is this XML correct?

I think a correct JSON response could be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "id_categoria": "3","categoria": "cat03"
            },
            {
                "id_categoria": "2","categoria": "cat02"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which its XML equivalent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rules>
        <id_categoria>3</id_categoria>
        <categoria>cat03</categoria>
    </rukes>
    <rules>
        <id_categoria>2</id_categoria>
        <categoria>cat02</categoria>
    </rules>
</data>
```

I'm lost. **Which is the correct format for JSON Response?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's invalid JSON. The web service really needs to fix it - it'd be possible to parse the JSON out with some work, but it **definitely** shouldn't be designed to work this way.

The valid JSON is between the `<body>` tags:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "id_categoria": "3",
            "categoria": "cat03"
        },
        {
            "id_categoria": "2",
            "categoria": "cat02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please add to your answer the correct response for this web service?